# grep command invert option not working

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to *filter out* the lines, that contain the **Permission denied** from the `find` command.

If I'm *running*:
`find ~ -name "fifo" | grep "Permission denied"`

The **output** is correct: 
`find: ‘/home/nroby/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/nroby/.dbus’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/nroby/.config/enchant’: Permission denied`

However if I'm using the `-v` option: `find ~ -name "fifo" | grep -v "Permission denied"`

The **output** is:

`find: ‘/home/nroby/.cache/dconf’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/nroby/.dbus’: Permission denied
/home/nroby/Desktop/Linux/fifo
find: ‘/home/nroby/.config/enchant’: Permission denied`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The lines saying `Permission denied` come from `stderr`, not `stdout`. The terminal displays both streams, but the pipe redirects only `stdout` (so with your command, `grep` never sees a line containing `Permission denied`).

So, if you only want to silence these messages, do this instead:

```
find ~ -name "fifo" 2>/dev/null
```

`2>` redirects `stderr`.

If you need to pipe both `stdout` and `stderr` for some reason (e.g., you want **other** error messages present in your output), you can do this:

```
find ~ -name "fifo" 2>&1 | grep -v "Permission denied"
```

`2>&1` redirects `stderr` to `stdout`.